# Configure Virtualbox to capture network traffic between 2 VMs on the same host from another physical machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wireshark, tcpdump

**My context is:**

- A physical machine with windows 10 (PC_Physcial_01) that host 2
  virtualbox linux VMs PC_VM_01 & PC_VM_02)
- An other physical machine dedicated to sniff network traffic
  (PC_Physcial_03) with a native linux and tcpdump (and wireshark)
  installed
- A last physical machine with windows 10 (PC_Physcial_02) that host 2
  virtualbox linux VMs PC_VM_03 & PC_VM_04)

Here a scheme of the configuration:

[image: Deployment_Scheme]

**The experience**

- A netcat is launched as server on PC_VM_01
- A netcat is launched as client on PC_VM_02 to PC_VM_01

=> I cannot sniff the traffic between these machines because virtualbox not use the NIC of the guest so the network traffic is not sent / received by all physical machine

To temporarly resolved my problem I use PC_VM_03 as a "router". In fact:

- A netcat is launched as server on PC_VM_01
- A netcat is launched as server on PC_VM_03
- A netcat is launched as client on PC_VM_02 to PC_VM_03
- A netcat is launched as client on PC_VM_03 to PC_VM_01

So I use PC_VM_03 to force the traffic to be emitted on physical network. Then the machine PC_Physcial_03 can sniff it.

**The problem**

My problem is to sniff using tcpdump (or wireshark) the network traffic between 2 virtualbox linux machine deployed on the same host from another physical machine (here PC_Physcial_03 should sniff traffic between PC_VM_01 & PC_VM_02).

But this traffic cannot be seen because it seems that virtualbox not use the host NIC for inter VMs (on the same host) network traffic.
I had confirmation of this behavior from virtualbox guide and forum (maybe VMware has the same behavior).

This is to avoid unuseful traffic (yes I agree) and risk of hack (I agree too). In my particular case this is for a specific use on an unexposed network so this is not a problem to expose the overall traffic or increase the network traffic load.
But in my case I want to force that and maybe a configuration can be done to avoid my "router" solution.

My virtualbox version is v6.1 (v6.1.16) with an ethernet bridge interface configuration. This is the screenshot of the NIC configuration:

[image: Virtualbox_NIC_Configuration]

Answer (score 2):

> But this traffic cannot be seen because it seems that virtualbox not use the host NIC for inter VMs (on the same host) network traffic. I had confirmation of this behavior from virtualbox guide and forum

"Using the host NIC" is not really something it *could* do anyway, as any packets sent through the host NIC would only go out, they would not be reflected back in. Traffic between VMs has to be forwarded internally in any case.

It's more about *how* VirtualBox performs that internal forwarding. Instead of just broadcasting each packet to all VMs, VirtualBox internally implements a learning bridge (i.e. a virtual switch) between the host and all 'bridged' VMs attached to the interface.

The "Promiscuous Mode" option in VM configuration is what controls whether that particular VM will be allowed to see all packets on this virtual switch, or whether it'll be restricted to only seeing its own packets.

Comment: Hello, the promiscuous mode is enabled: I updated the screenshot. I made a mistake when doing the screenshot : bad VM configuration.